# Access logged_in user in modules :: web2py

Tags: python-2.7, web2py, web2py-modules

I am working in a web2py application, where I need to access current user in modules, so is there any possibility to access current user in web2py modules, and yes then How can I access this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the thread local [`current` object](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Sharing-the-global-scope-with-modules-using-the-current-object). Assuming you are using the standard name `auth` for the `Auth` object, in a module, you can do:

```
from gluon import current

def myfunction():
    user = current.globalenv['auth'].user
```

You can also explicitly add the user object as an attribute of `current` within a model file:

```
from gluon import current
current.auth_user = auth.user
```

And then in the module, you can access `current.auth_user`.

As noted [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Warning--Do-not-use-the-current-object-in-global-scope-in-a-module), you should not assign properties of the `current` object to top level variables or class attributes within the module (this is because the `current` object is local to each thread, but such assignments will only take place once, when the module is first imported).

Another option is simply to pass the `auth` object to your functions or classes from the module. For example, in a module:

```
def myfunction(auth):
    user = auth.user
```

Comment: when I am trying to access it in module like this 
from gluon import current
current.auth_user

then I am getting this error.
*** AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'auth_user'